# Div height depending to client screen

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the class YB_full_content_img_header. I want to change the height div with 60% from current height depending to client screen width.

```
var screen = jQuery(window).width();
    var div= jQuery(".YB_full_content_img_header");
    div.css('height',60%???);
```

My code didn't work. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle please?

Comment: try `$div.css('height','60%');`

Comment: @reporter `div` is a variable so $ isn't needed is it?

Comment: @AndyHolmes div contains a jquery object. This is different to plain Javascript. Most of the methods works, though not all.

Comment: @reporter, andy means that the variable is named `div` in the code, not `$div` (*as in your comment*).

Comment: @AndyHolmes you seem to have a wrong understanding of how variables work in js. the $ in front of variables is just a convention to help the developer. If you name the variable `div` then only `div` exists, and `$div` will cause an error as that variable is not defined.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli In all my time I developed with Jquery (V1.x) I could use this way and as I had written before. If you don't use $ some Jquery method could not apply.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli haha no i do understand, i just didn't explain my point very well :P

Comment: @AndyHolmes oups.. sorry that comment was directed to reporter.. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @reporter that is just wrong. what you describe cannot happen. the `$` is a function you call for creating the jquery object object. it has nothing to do with how you name the variable in which you store that jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value as a string to the `.css` method

```
div.css('height','60%');
```

if it is depended on the window width you will have to make a test

```
if (screen < 500){ /*500 is an example here*/
    div.css('height','60%');
}
```

---

**Update** of answer due to the comments

The OP wanted to keep a fixed ration of width/height on some element.

The solution was to resize the div as the browser width changed

in terms of the OP's code the update is

```
$(function() {
    var div = $('.YB_full_content_img_header');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = div.width();
        div.css('height', width * 60/100);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

but an alternate option is to use the CSS padding trick ([Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div))

Comment: @AndreeaTirgovatu you want to be 60% of the width ? (at all times ?)

Comment: 60% of the current div height all times

Comment: var screen = jQuery(window).width();
    var background = jQuery(".YB_full_content_img_header");
    var bgHeight = background.height(); //current height
    if (screen) {
        background.css("height", bgHeight-'60%');
    }

Comment: @AndreeaTirgovatu you just need to do the math then .. `.css('height, bgHeight*60/100)`

Comment: I thnik something is wrong. Maybe is not possible to depend to screen width... just screen height.

Comment: @AndreeaTirgovatu can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve ? your example codes show that you want it relevant to height, but you mention you want it relevant to width. Please describe the actual need (detailed)

Comment: @AndreeaTirgovatu have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mr8gj/672/ in case what you need is to keep a fixed ration on your element (*while the screen is resized*)

Comment: your jsfiddle solved my issue.Thanks. And for everybody, I tried to reduce with 60% my height div from the current  height but depending screen width and resize solve my problem. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you intend depending the height of browser, determine the height and the width of your image. If this is correct, then you can do it e.g. as follows:

```
$('#Your_Div').css({'width':(parseInt((60*screen.availWidth)/100)+'px'),'height':(parseInt((60*screen.availHeight)/100)+'px') });
```

You cah get the 60% the height of your div as follows: `parseInt((60*$('#Your_Div_Id').height())/100)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                windowHeight=$(window).height();
                newHeight=Math.round((60/100)*windowHeight);    //60 % OF CURRENT WINDOW HEIGHT                         
                $('.YB_full_content_img_header').css('height',newHeight);               
            });
    </script>
```

This may be helpful.